# stylelint on create-react-app @import-normalize throw error

Tags: create-react-app, stylelint

I followed this doc to add CSS reset to my app.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-css-reset/#indexcss

But it showed this message:

[image]

```
"stylelint": {
"extends": "stylelint-config-recommended",
"rules": {
  "at-rule-no-unknown": null
}
```

How to fix this problem?it is annoying...

Comment: I just turned off "CSS at rule" in a WebStorm settings, under inspections > css.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this warning you just need to add this line to`.vscode/settings.json` inside your project (you can create this file if it doesn't already exist):

```json
{
  "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
}
```

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-css-reset/#indexcss

Answer (score 1):

**For VS Code** -

To make the VS Code recognise this custom CSS directive, you can provide custom data for VS Code's CSS Language Service as mentioned here - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/docs/customData.md.

Create a CSS custom data set file with the following info. Place it at location `.vscode/custom.css-data.json` relative to the project root.

```json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "properties": [],
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@import-normalize",
      "description": "bring in normalize.css styles"
    }
  ],
  "pseudoClasses": [],
  "pseudoElements": []
}
```

Now, if you don't have already, create a `.vscode\settings.json` file relative to project root. Add a field with key "css.customData" and value as the path to custom data set. For example,

```json
{
  "css.customData": ["./.vscode/custom.css-data.json"]
}
```

Now, you will no longer get "Unknown at rule" warning. When you hover over "@import-normalize", you will see the description you set for it in `custom.css-data.json`

[image: "bring in normalize.css styles" shown in tooltip when "@import-normalize" is hovered]

Answer (score 0):

`@import-normalize` is a non-standard at-rule. From the [rule's documentation](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/at-rule-no-unknown):

> This rule considers at-rules defined in the CSS Specifications, up to and including Editor's Drafts, to be known.

However, the rule has [an `ignoreAtRules` secondary option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/at-rule-no-unknown#ignoreatrules-regex-regex-string) for exactly this use case, where you can list the non-standard imports you are using.

For example, in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended",
    "rules": {
      "at-rule-no-unknown": [true, {
        "ignoreAtRules": ["import-normalise"]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Or within your `.stylelintrc` file:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended",
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": [true, {
      "ignoreAtRules": ["import-normalise"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `stylelint` really come with CRA?

Comment: I tried this method with CRA (create-react-app). It did not work.